# How to combine two activerecord relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have model `User` and `User` has column `provider`.

Provider can be `google`, `facebook` or `nil`.

I want to make scope, that will output all users, except users with provider `google` and older that `some time`.

I tried to do it with two scopes:

```rb
scope :not_google_authorised, -> { where(provider: [nil, 'facebook']) }
scope :newest_google, -> { where(provider: 'google').where("created_at < ?", Time.now)}
...
users = User.not_google_authorised
users << User.newest_google
```

It get right results, but it changed class of `users`.
I need that `users` will be activerecord relations, not array.
I tried do:

```rb
users = User.not_google_authorised
users.merge(User.newest_google)
#or
users.or(User.newest_google)
```

But it doesn't work for me.

How can i combine this 2 scopes, so `users` will be activerecord relations, or how can i write one scope instead their?

I use ruby v3.3.7 and rails v4.1

Comment: You could try combining the queries in a where. `User.where("provider IN (?) OR (provider = ? AND created_at > ?)", [nil, 'facebook'], 'google', Time.now)` This is just a rough draft, but hopefully can help :D

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#or` did not exist until rails 5.

Also the current stable ruby version is `3.0.0` which means you cannot be using `3.3.7` as it does not exist yet (and may never exist).

`merge` will combine using `AND` (intersection).

So your best bet is to use raw SQL where or `Arel` like:

```
where(
  User.arel_table[:provider].eq(nil).or(
    User.arel_table[:provider].eq('facebook')
  ).or(
    User.arel_table[:provider].eq('google').and(
      User.arel_table[:created_at].lt(Time.now)
    )
  )
)
```

This should result in:

```
SELECT 
  "users".*
FROM 
  "users" 
WHERE 
  ("users"."provider" IS NULL OR "users"."provider" = 'facebook')
   OR ( "users"."provider" = 'google' AND "users"."created_at" < [SOME TIME]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do this, not super optimized but gets the job done.

```rb
not_google_auth_ids = User.not_google_authorized.ids
newest_ids = User.newest_google.ids
ids = not_google_auth_ids + newest_ids

users = User.where(id: ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can right in a single scope that way:

**scope :not_authorised, -> { where("(provider = ? and created_at < ?) or provider != ?",'google', Time.now, 'google' }**

Comment: `!=` will not work here because it will not show `NULL` values. `NULL` is not comparable so it is neither equal to "google" nor not equal to "google" (`NULL` is not even equal to `NULL`)